# Timeout issue in django with nginx and gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have few rest API,s in django that take more then one minute to get Data. Because there are more then 20 million records in database. But It show time out after one minute . How to increase timeout ?. I have searched the internet and made changes in Nginx and Gunicorn accordingly but It still show time out after one minute when i hit the API with postman.

Nginx Config file -

```
    location / {

proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

proxy_pass http://unix:/home/neeraj/run/gunicorn.sock;

proxy_connect_timeout 500;

proxy_read_timeout 500s;  }
```

Gunicorn.service file -

```
ExecStart=/home/neeraj/cashvenv/bin/gunicorn --error-logfile /home/neeraj/run/gerror.log --workers 3 --timeout 500 --bind unix:/home/neeraj/run/gunicorn.sock Cash.wsgi:application
```

edit nginx logs

```
 - - [13/Feb/2022:15:49:25 +0530] "POST /reporting/dashboard/cards HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4" "
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Can you please share the nginx error log. Who closes the conenction? The upstream or the browser. How did you send the request? From a webbrowser?

Comment: @TimoStark nginx log atteched . i am hitting api with postman. even if i do curl it still show timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was the issue from AWS Side. my server had a Load Balancers attached to it in which time out was set for 60 sec .

Comment: Yes. Was just about asking this. Error code 499 means the connection to NGINX was closed by the client. An LoadBalancer is often the problem. Glad it is working!